# jQuery: .wrapAll around multiple, repeating Elements

Tags: html, jquery, wrapper, repeat

I have some sort of form that feels a little messy since each row isn't really wrapped by a div or ul/li, which makes styling difficult. So I wanted to use jQuery to wrap it up since I can't really edit the HTML directly.

Right now it looks somewhat like this:

```
<p class="A">Blabla</p>
<input class="B">

<p class="A">Blabla</p>
<input class="B">

<p class="A">Blabla</p>
<input class="B">

<p class="A">Blabla</p>
<input class="B">
```

And I was trying to use this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    $( ".A, .B" ).wrapAll("<div class='C'></div>");
});
```

Of course this puts a div around ALL As and Bs as a "block".
But what I want is to have this div around each line.

So as a result, I basically want this:

```
<div class="C">
  <p class="A">Blabla</p>
  <input class="B">
</div>

<div class="C">
  <p class="A">Blabla</p>
  <input class="B">
</div>

<div class="C">
  <p class="A">Blabla</p>
  <input class="B">
</div>

<div class="C">
  <p class="A">Blabla</p>
  <input class="B">
</div>
```

Can you help? (:

Note: It doesn't have to be div for me. ul/li would be fine, too, but perhaps is more work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use each function to go through each selected `A` class and then use add function to create a new jQuery object with `B` class by getting immediately following sibling with help of next function and then wrap them using wrapAll function.

```
$(".A").each(function(){
    $(this).add($(this).next(".B")).wrapAll("<div class='C'></div>");
})
```

and if you want to add all in between `A` class and another `A` class,

```
$(".A").each(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil(".A").addBack().wrapAll("<div class='C'></div>")
})
```

This one will solve your above problem also

Comment: Hmm, this one only seems to wrap the p-element / .A, but does not include .B :(

Comment: Wait, to be more precise: IF there is something in-between, then it only wraps .A

Comment: No @Manisch , Please try and let me know, it will wrap both .A and .B and second one will add all Elements between two .A(including only 1st .A) in wrapper

Comment: The last one looks good, but I think there was a small error. This one seems to work now: '$(".A").each(function(){     $(this).nextUntil(".A").addBack().add($(this).next('.B')).wrapAll("<div class='C'></div>") })' - so the first .B should be an .A...? Anyways, thanks a lot for your help! <3

Comment: @Manisch you don't need `add($(this).next('.B'))` , please try once, Glad I could help!!!

Answer (score 2):

Using `each()`

```js
$(".A + .B").each(function() {
  $(this).prev().addBack().wrapAll("<div class='C'></div>");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="A">Blabla</p>
<input class="B">

<p class="A">Blabla</p>
<input class="B">

<p class="A">Blabla</p>
<input class="B">

<p class="A">Blabla</p>
<input class="B">
```

Comment: Thanks, it almost works!

Just discovered another issue: Some of the lines have a <label class="D"> in between, which messes things up a little. 

Can I add some sort of variable/placeholder in the middle like:
$(".A + *everything in-between, if there is something* + .B") ?

Comment: use [nextUntil()](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) to select everything inbetween